# how to get parameter from request sent in JMS Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMS publisher and have a request xml copied on text message area , this xml has a node where i have put a beanshell script so that at each request new timestamp gets appends to the node to keep each request unique. How can i get the list of that node for each request sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Amend your Beanshell code to store generated timestamp into a JMeter Variable like:

   ```
   ${__BeanShell(long ts = System.currentTimeMillis(); vars.put("timestamp"\,String.valueOf(ts)); return ts;)}
   ```

   [image: Beanshell Timestamp]

   It will store generated timestamp into a JMeter Variable called `${timestamp}`
2. Add the following line to *user.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   sample_variables=timestamp
   ```
3. Next time you run JMeter you'll be able to see generated timestamp values in the last column of .jtl results file.

See [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) User Manual chapter for details.

By the way, you can generate timestamp without calling Beanshell, JMeter provides [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function which can return current time in different formats. See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) article for comprehensive explanation.